# Find and replace layerfile paths

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.5, layer-file

Is there a way I can find and replace all layerfile paths in a folder?

I have over 150 layer files that have incorrect paths after a server migration changed the path of the layerfiles. I have found ways to change the layerfile path within an mxd but nothing on how to change all within a specific folder.

Comment: Please specify the version of your ArcGIS or add some appropriate tags

Answer (score 3):

You can change all or just a part of links in your mxd this way:

1. Open ArcCatalog and navigate to your mxd file
2. Right-click and select "Set data sources"
3. Highlight the ones you need to change or click "Select All"
4. Click "Replace" or "Replace All" and specify a new path(s).
5. Click "Ok" - this will save a copy of your .mxd file with updated paths

Comment: I am looking to replace all paths within a folder not an mxd.

Comment: What do you mean by "replace paths within a folder"? Is this folder referenced in a project?

Comment: I have 150 layerfiles in a folder on our server. They are not referenced currently in any mxd but the data the layerfile references has been moved. I need to redirect the layerfile path to the new location on server.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of examples of doing this using arcpy. Here is some quick code I have used in the past for mass updating .mxd data sources. You should be easily able to adapt it to layer files using the examples here:https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/updatingandfixingdatasources.htm

```
import arcpy     
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Temp\mxds"  
new_location  = r"C:\Temp\Newsourcedata"  
for file in arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd"):
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(file)  
    mxd.findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths(" " , new_location )  
    mxd.save()
```